# Distrbution of Matrix times vector

Tags: probability-distributions, random-matrices

Given the distribution of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, how to find the distribution of $Y = AX$, where $Y$ and $X$ are $n\times 1$ vector and X is deterministic.

Comment: I believe it would help to know what assumptions you make on the *distribution* of the random matrix $A$. For instance, if the entries of $A$ are i.i.d. copies of some $\mathbb C$-valued random variables, the approach to solving this question could be very different than the approach used if $A$ was a Haar unitary matrix.